# can I cancel Power BI premium per use license before the end of subscription cycle

Tags: powerbi

I am thinking to buy power BI premium per user license subscription. I have concern here, can I cancel the subscription of the license before the end of the subscription cycle?

Would anyone help me take decision on it?  Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to debugging/help

Comment: Could u please suggest me an appropriate venue to get the needed information besides microsoft site.

Comment: PPU is a monthly subscription.